# ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema! weird behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!` line in my rails_helper.rb, which gives the ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError if some migrations are pending in the test environment. However when I run `rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` after the error emerges, it tries to run all migrations from scratch which results in `Relation table_name already exists` error, rather than running single migrations. When I check the migration status it says `Schema migrations table does not exist yet.` Somehow `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!` unloads the schema migrations table when it's supposed to load it?

If I run test migrations before I run RSpec and it hits the `maintain_test_schema` everything is ok. Also the above problem is solved by running `rails db:migrate:reset RAILS_ENV=test` but I'm really curious about what causes it in the first place.

Comment: Have u found any solution?

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari No, just using `rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` for now